# Android push Notification with json data

Tags: android, json, push-notification, push

I am making a basic news application. App is getting data from third party json api. I want to implement push notifications so that whenever there is new data then a notification is displayed to the user. I am confused as how to check whether json api has some new records and then how to send notification based on the new record

Comment: Use Firebase or Gcm service https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: If your api doesn't notice that new records are created, I think you need to implement data polling in service. Make service that getting json from api periodically. However you must consider it cause lots of communication.